# java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed [help]

Tags: java, jdbc

here is my code:

check this please

having problem

Result set code is working

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        new MyProject();
        model1.setRowCount(0);
        Statement s1=MyProject.conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=s1.executeQuery("select * from myproject4");
        while(rs.next()) {
            //System.out.println("147");
            s1.executeUpdate("insert into myproject2(cname,caddress,saleId,SNo,Name,Price,Quantity,Tax,total,Date)values('"
                    + rs.getString("cname") + "','" + rs.getString("caddress") + "','" + rs.getString("saleId") 
                    + "','" + rs.getString("sno") + "','" + rs.getString("Name") + "','" 
                    + rs.getString("Price") + "','" + rs.getString("Quantity") + "','" + rs.getString("Tax") 
                    + "','" + rs.getString("total") + "','" + rs.getString("Date") + "')");
        }
        s1.executeUpdate("delete from myproject4");
        jTextField5.setText("");
        jTextField6.setText("");
        model1.setRowCount(0);
        money=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Grand total - " + gtotal + '\n' + "Enter Money");
        money1=Double.valueOf(money)-gtotal;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Change - "  + money1);
        new NewJFrame6().setVisible(true);
    } catch(SQLException | HeadlessException | NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Resultset is working but the exception occuring the obvious progran is not running further

Comment: Can you post the full exception message that you are getting?

Comment: What is your understanding of the error message?